# Having trouble calling Bloc.observer in main.dart

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

[image]

When I call Bloc.observer in main.dart, it doesn't work

Comment: Always post sinppets of your code, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it through zone guarded

> Runs body in its own error zone.

> Creates a new zone using Zone.fork based on zoneSpecification and zoneValues, then runs body in that zone and returns the result.

```
 await runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      await BlocOverrides.runZoned(
        () async => runApp(MyApp()),
        blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(),
      );
    },
    (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
  );
```